# what are the reason that method all() inside my class User fetch only on result?

Tags: php

crated  a class for users inside this class there is method name all() this method sppouse that it fetches all of the data from databae but it fetch the first result only while i am using foreach()

```
class User
{
    public int $id;
    public string $first_name;
    public string $last_name;
    public string $email;
    public string $password;
    public string $hash;
    public bool $active;
    protected PDO $Connection;
    protected array $resultSet;
    public function __construct(PDO $Connection)
    {
        $this->Connection = $Connection;
    }

    public function all(): array|bool
    {
        if($statement = $this->Connection->query('select * from users'))
        {
            if($result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,'User',[$this->Connection]))
            {
                foreach ($result as $users)
                {
                    $this->resultSet['id'] = $users->id;
                    $this->resultSet['first_name'] = $users->first_name;
                    $this->resultSet['last_name'] = $users->last_name;
                    $this->resultSet['email'] = $users->email;
                    $this->resultSet['password'] = $users->password;
                    $this->resultSet['hash'] = $users->hash;
                    $this->resultSet['active'] = $users->active;
                    return $this->resultSet;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're returning from inside the `foreach` which breaks the iteration, here's a quick demo to illustrate the issue. https://3v4l.org/IeFAG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
return $this->resultSet;
```

you're ending the method. Move that line outside of the foreach block, one line below. Also remember that since you're replacing the same indexes in the resultSet, no adding a new record, it will contain the last record only. Try something like

```
$this->resultSet[] = [
    'id' => $users->id,
    ...
];
```

That will push a record for each loop time.

Comment: @ Juan Eizmendi i have another question do i have to make the proparties in that class private or protected

Comment: It depends on what you need, think who will access them, if some need sanitation, but start from private and update as need.